# What's the best way to do relationship on teams with leader and users

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm making a laravel App and I'm dealing with a problem.

```
table users:
-id
-name

table teams:
-id
-name

table team_agent
-agent_id (users.id)
-team_id

table team_leader
-leader_id (users.id)
-team_id
```

One team can have only one leader and multiple agents.
One agent can be part of only one team.
One leader can be assigned to only one team.

On the User Model i have the function team() which should return the team of the user.

What is the best practice if I want to have 2 functions on the User Model. One that return the team of the user (if is agent) and one that returns the team (if is leader).

Am I doing it correctly with pivot table for the leader part? Or should I put the leader_id in the team table ?
I really don't know how to handle this part.

---

Or should i add the leader_id to the teams table and team_id on the users table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would an eloquent model called roles. Which would track which user has which role for which team. The business logic would make sure that one team only has one leader, and that one player only belongs to one team.

**Table roles**

- user_id
- team_id
- role_type_id

**Table role_type** (containing leader and user)

- id
- name

**Table users**

- id
- name

**Table teams**

- id
- name